# Function having undefined variable in nested for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

When I run this, it claims x is undefined on the on the line with the for loop.

Full code:

```
function getCustomerNumbers() {
    var customerNumbers = [];
    customerNumbers.push(12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43);
    return customerNumbers;
}
function getWinningNumbers() {
    var winningNumbers = [];
    winningNumbers.push(12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43);    
    return winningNumbers;
}
function checkNumbers(x, y) {    
    var matches = 0;
    for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<y.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] == y[j]) {
                matches++;
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
function displayResult() {
    checkNumbers(getWinningNumbers(), getCustomerNumbers())
    alert("This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n\n" + getWinningNumbers().toString() + 
    "\n\nThe Customer's Number is:\n\n" + getCustomerNumbers().toString() + "\n\nNumber of Matches:" + checkNumbers());
}
function init() {
    displayResult();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Later it runs, with arrays going into values x and y. It ran fine when it was just x as an array and one for loop.

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: What are you putting in for x when it doesn't run? ".length" only works on arrays or certain collections.

Comment: it works fine with me !!
you must did something wrong when you call it

Comment: running perfectly for me http://jsfiddle.net/tv4gcucw/

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `x` is undefined. Look at it in the debugger. Show us how you're calling this function.

Comment: what is the error? Your code runs fine with two array inputs http://jsfiddle.net/zfzu7wyo/

Comment: It works fine as long as you pass 2 arrays....  You should `var` your variables otherwise they will be considered global variables.

Comment: var does not solve it, I run it in another function, where x and y are arrays returned by separate functions.

Comment: Then how are you calling it? We can't see your code.

Comment: `function checkNumbers(var x, var y)` -- why do you have `var` listed in the parameters?  It should be `function checkNumbers( x, y)`

Comment: @ps2goat You've just found the missing vars for `i` and  `j`?

Comment: i had x, y: changed it to check with another comment

Comment: Are those "getters" real code you have, or have you possibly some AJAX call to get the data?

Comment: Yes, that's the real code

Comment: Check my answer.  you're not passing anything in for x and y on the second call to `checkNumbers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code is still missing something, as the first `function` is missing.

The next thing I found was the second call to `checkNumbers` doesn't pass anything in.

```
function displayResult() {
    checkNumbers(getWinningNumbers(), getCustomerNumbers())
    alert("This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n\n" + getWinningNumbers().toString() + 
    "\n\nThe Customer's Number is:\n\n" + getCustomerNumbers().toString() + "\n\nNumber of Matches:" + checkNumbers()); //<-- where are the parameters?
}
```

Working code:

```js
function getCustomerNumbers(){
var customerNumbers = [];
    customerNumbers.push(12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43);
    return customerNumbers;
}
function getWinningNumbers() {
    var winningNumbers = [];
    winningNumbers.push(12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43);    
    return winningNumbers;
}
function checkNumbers(x, y) {    
    var matches = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<y.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] == y[j]) {
                matches++;
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}

function displayResult() {    
    alert("This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n\n" + getWinningNumbers().toString() + 
    "\n\nThe Customer's Number is:\n\n" + getCustomerNumbers().toString() + "\n\nNumber of Matches:" + checkNumbers(getWinningNumbers(), getCustomerNumbers())
         );
}

displayResult();
```

Comment: apologies, left out the top line where I called the function

Comment: Then the code you posted is different from what you're using. My snippet works.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `checkNumbers` twice - the first time passing in valid values for `x` & `y` and the second time passing in nothing

```
function displayResult() {
    // Good, but ignores result
    checkNumbers(getWinningNumbers(), getCustomerNumbers()) 
    //Nothing passed in
    alert("This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n\n" + getWinningNumbers().toString() + 
    "\n\nThe Customer's Number is:\n\n" + getCustomerNumbers().toString() + "\n\nNumber of Matches:" + checkNumbers()); 
}
```